# Why does Linux get slow?

Tags: linux, firefox, linux-mint

I've read on this page (http://www.whylinuxisbetter.net/) benefits of a Linux system and it says that it doesn't get slow by time (in contrary to Windows), but mine does. Also, I've noticed that after long uptime, it starts to "lag" (e.g. when I press CTRL + T in Firefox to open new tab, I must wait almost a second). I assume that's cause of the uptime, but I'm not sure. Btw, (sorry if it's off-topic), page says that Linux doesn't have to update, but I have to update/patch every 2-3 days and it's irritating, especially if I don't use that programs. My question is: why does this happen and what can I do to make it as fast as it was the day I installed it?

Comment: Which linux distribution did you try? And have you installed it on a separate partition? You could try other stackexchange websites, i.e. for Ubuntu you can solve all your problems if you post your question at http://www.askubuntu.com

Comment: You are getting downvotes (not mine) because i) you have not told us _which_ GNU/Linux you are using. Linux distributions are very different to one another. ii) You have not described your symptoms, just that firefox is slower. What other programs are running? Does this continue after rebooting? What else is slow? iii) Nobody forces you to update, don't if you don't want to. Anyway, again, that will depend on your distribution iv) Nobody said that windows gets slower after long uptime, the problem you refer to is all the crap that collects over time. Have a look at [ask].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's solve your problems:

> when I press CTRL + T in Firefox to open new tab, I must wait almost a
> second

1. Have you tried **clearing your browser history and bookmarks**?
2. You can clear other elements (log files and whatnot) using `bleachbit` (install the package/program using a package/software manager of your linux distribution)
3. Are you sure it's not an addon causing the delay? You can use **less addons**, in order to make it faster
4. In order for apps to load faster, install the package `preload`. It will load faster in memory apps you use frequently. In Ubuntu you just have to install it, everything else is taken care of automatically.
5. Speed depends on the **linux distribution** you use and the **hardware** you have (graphics card, CPU and RAM memory mostly). For example, [standard ubuntu linux desktop](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) is not very good for older machines nowadays, but that's why they support "[Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/)". You can also try [Linux mint](http://www.linuxmint.com/) (with Cinnamon desktop and no effects)
6. It also depends on how you installed your linux. For example, linux distro Ubuntu has an option to "install in windows", without partitioning your hard drive, which is regarded as a bad idea. **You should install your Ubuntu/Linux distribution on a separate partition**.

   Burn your linux distro on a CD or install it on a USB -- they are called "Live CDs or USBs" so you can use them to use the system on-the-fly (without installing anything) and to use the installer when you feel comfortable on a separate partition.

> page says that Linux doesn't have to update, but I have to
> update/patch every 2-3 days and it's irritating, especially if I don't
> use that programs

1. You can remove any programs/packages you don't use, provided that other programs do not depend on them. Use the software/package manager.
2. You may find "barebone" linux distributions, light as a feather and you may install what you want and need. I personally wouldn't suggest them for newcomers because they need configuration and setup, but you may try [arch linux](https://www.archlinux.org/) or [tiny core linux](http://tinycorelinux.net/).
3. http://www.whylinuxisbetter.net/ also mentions "[Linux protects your computer](http://www.whylinuxisbetter.net/items/security/index.php?lang=)" and "[Update all your software with a single click](http://www.whylinuxisbetter.net/items/global_update/index.php?lang=)". I suggest that you read them. Updates are being provided to increase your security, a feature that Windows tries to apply nowadays.

   Also, you can set up in some linux distros (like Ubuntu) to install the software automatically, without you ever clicking or being bothered -- look for "software properties" in Ubuntu.

To sum up, if it's slow, try Lubuntu, if it's semi-slow, try Linux Mint, but if you're an adventurer, try Arch Linux.

Comment: I'm using Linux Mint and it is older computer. I disabled some extensions and deleted history and cache and it solved my slow-firefox problem (now it makes sense why it gets slower after long uptime). Thanks for great answer and I'll try programs you mentioned!

Comment: @Bade if it gets slower after long uptime, there's something wrong. You probably have very little RAM and the system starts [swapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging#Terminology). Mint and Ubuntu offer very heavy desktop environments, you should try something like [XFCE](http://www.xfce.org/) if you have an older machine.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from the [link](http://www.whylinuxisbetter.net/items/old_and_sluggish/index.php?lang=) given.

> Why does your Windows get slower day after day?
>
> Windows has a number of design flaws, resulting in it becoming slower
>   and slower and not lasting very long. You've probably heard more than
>   once someone say "My computer is getting sluggish, I'm gonna
>   reinstall". Reinstalling Windows solves the problem... until next
>   time.
>
> You may think this is just how computers work: they're very new
>   technology, and not really stable yet. Well, try Linux and you'll be
>   surprised. Five years from now, your system will be just as fast and
>   responsive as the day you installed it, not to mention that you won't
>   have any viruses, adware, trojans, worms, etc., that would force you
>   to reinstall anyway.
>
> I have managed to convince many people to switch to Linux, while
>   keeping Windows on their hard disk, because they needed to use some
>   piece of software that Linux doesn't have (eg Autocad), so they use
>   both systems. Since the day they switched, most of them have
>   reinstalled Windows about once in a year or two; but Linux didn't let
>   them down, and is still running perfectly well and is still snappy
>   today.
>
> Linux lets you spend more time working, less time reinstalling over
>   and over again.

I haven't seen any concrete reason **why** Linux is faster in this text, other than *try Linux and you'll be surprised*.

The person who wrote the text also said Windows has design flaws... well, what are they?

Comment: Why am I'm getting negative votes? If it's that dumb question, I'd be pleased if person who gave me negative vote at least says why he/she did it...

Comment: Well, this is my opinion... any system will eventually get slower, because you keep filling it junk. The link you gave is biased towards Linux. And there are many flavors of Linux to choose, some better, some worse, depending on planned usage.

Comment: Ok, but nevermind distributions for a minute or even system slowing by time - Why does it take that long to open new tab when CPU usage is around 15% and RAM around 20%? I don't have junk background programs. Only firefox and document viewer.

Comment: This is highly dependent on what you have in Firefox (as in Extras and such), but Firefox has become somewhat bloated. Maybe you have a filled cache, or a very deep history or download history. If your problem is just about Firefox taking too much time, then my suggestion would be to ask a new question, adding maximum detail.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, first of all, everything will get slower if you use it badly and linux is not an exception. The cause of it might be some junk applications running in the background.

Now, linux's advantages are:

- Almost no malicious software, it can and will slow down your computer
- Linux partitions (ext4) rarely needs to be defragmented. Widnows uses `ntfs`, so it gets way more fragmentations than ext4. On normal use, you won't need to defragment.
- No `registry` for linux. Registry errors might slow down your computer.
- It is easy to get junk software and run it on background on windows. I have had these issues many times. You are looking for some application and end up having 4-5 junk applications that run on startup and use your CPU power.

I am a linux fan but to be honest, if you keep your windows properly, you won't have any issues with it. On this matter, nobody can claim that windows is designed badly and it slows down.

Comment: There exists malicious software for Linux, it just isn't targeted more because fewer people use it. Any file-system will eventually fragment, even ext4 and NTFS. They, in comparison with FAT, just handle it a lot better (because of journaling, error checking, and other technologies). And since Linux is approaching Windows usability (with Ubuntu and all), you can get junk software at will...

Comment: @DoktoroReichard I may agree with you only about partitions, because my claim was a bit extreme (Linux partitions (ext4) are not getting fragmentations), but take a look at [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/115229/htg-explains-why-linux-doesnt-need-defragmenting/) article, it rarely gets fragmentations on normal use.

Comment: Like I said, newer file systems handle fragmentation better. But, **by design**, it will always be there.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard about malicious and junk software. I have claimed that his problem on linux are junk software and I also said `almost no` malicious software.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard I will edit my answer to include that there are fragmentations. Still, I don't think anybody will notice those fragmentations while using ext4.

Comment: Like I said, fragmentation isn't the problem it was 15 years ago. However this is dragging to a debate, so I'm stopping my tracks here.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard sorry, but your suggestion that most Linux users would have to defrag *any* FS is incorrect. In theory, any FS will frag, but that's ignoring tools like [reserved root space](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/7950/41024) or even `/tmp`. Linux doesn't just handle fragmentation better, it avoids it more than Windows does.